# why is my tableView not pushing to the detailViewController inside my tableView?

Tags: swift, uikit

Im creating a twitter clone and for some reason when a user taps on a cell it should go to the detailViewController to show them more about the tweet but it never pushes. And I know the problem is not something like chest to make sure you have the correct storyboard ID because when I make the tableView the initial view controller it pushes to the detail view controller. So IDK if this a bug in the code or in the view hierarchy  etc.

I tried just doing a segue but it was the same problem and made sure that its the right class in storyBoard.

here's my GitHub to see if anyone can find the bug or problem with the tableView cell not pushing to the detailViewController,

https://github.com/imjusttrynabelikeElon/twitter/tree/main

here's some code snippets as well of where the bug may be.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olpdm.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvGBF.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have cloned your project and checked.
This is working :

```
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    
        guard let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "detail") as? TwitterHomeViewDetailViewController else {
        print("failed to instantiate detail view controller")
        return
        }
```

Comment: wow thats crazy. all that time one line of code fixed it! Thanks man

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
if let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "detail") as? TwitterHomeViewDetailViewController {
    // Do what you want.
} else {
    assertionFailure("Failed!")
}
```